# Vectorized searchsorted numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Assume that I have two arrays `A` and `B`, where both `A` and `B` are `m x n`. My goal is now, for each row of `A` and `B`, to find where I should insert the elements of row `i` of `A` in the corresponding row of `B`. That is, I wish to apply `np.digitize` or `np.searchsorted` to each row of `A` and `B`.

My naive solution is to simply iterate over the rows. However, this is far too slow for my application. My question is therefore: is there a vectorized implementation of either algorithm that I haven't managed to find?

Comment: Would the elements in each row of A and B be sorted?

Comment: Yes, they are. I'm basically implementing systematic resampling

Comment: If you show your current implementation we may indicate what to improve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can add each row some offset as compared to the previous row. We would use the same offset for both arrays. The idea is to use `np.searchsorted` on flattened version of input arrays thereafter and thus each row from `b` would be restricted to find sorted positions in the corresponding row in `a`. Additionally, to make it work for negative numbers too, we just need to offset for the minimum numbers as well.

So, we would have a vectorized implementation like so -

```
def searchsorted2d(a,b):
    m,n = a.shape
    max_num = np.maximum(a.max() - a.min(), b.max() - b.min()) + 1
    r = max_num*np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
    p = np.searchsorted( (a+r).ravel(), (b+r).ravel() ).reshape(m,-1)
    return p - n*(np.arange(m)[:,None])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [173]: def searchsorted2d_loopy(a,b):
     ...:     out = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=int)
     ...:     for i in range(len(a)):
     ...:         out[i] = np.searchsorted(a[i],b[i])
     ...:     return out
     ...: 

In [174]: # Setup input arrays
     ...: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(10000,20))
     ...: b = np.random.randint(11,99,(10000,20))
     ...: a = np.sort(a,1)
     ...: b = np.sort(b,1)
     ...: 

In [175]: np.allclose(searchsorted2d(a,b),searchsorted2d_loopy(a,b))
Out[175]: True

In [176]: %timeit searchsorted2d_loopy(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.6 ms per loop

In [177]: %timeit searchsorted2d(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks Divakar - your solutions are always clean and elegant!

Comment: Does using the `side` parameter equal to `'right'` affect the result?  My guess is no.

Comment: @piRSquared Should be okay with that param set to `right`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Divakar is ideal for integer data, but beware of precision issues for floating point values, especially if they span multiple orders of magnitude (e.g. `[[1.0, 2,0, 3.0, 1.0e+20],...]`).  In some cases `r` may be so large that applying `a+r` and `b+r` wipes out the original values you're trying to run `searchsorted` on, and you're just comparing `r` to `r`.

To make the approach more robust for floating-point data, you could embed the row information into the arrays as part of the values (as a structured dtype), and run searchsorted on these structured dtypes instead.

```
def searchsorted_2d (a, v, side='left', sorter=None):
  import numpy as np

  # Make sure a and v are numpy arrays.
  a = np.asarray(a)
  v = np.asarray(v)

  # Augment a with row id
  ai = np.empty(a.shape,dtype=[('row',int),('value',a.dtype)])
  ai['row'] = np.arange(a.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)
  ai['value'] = a

  # Augment v with row id
  vi = np.empty(v.shape,dtype=[('row',int),('value',v.dtype)])
  vi['row'] = np.arange(v.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)
  vi['value'] = v

  # Perform searchsorted on augmented array.
  # The row information is embedded in the values, so only the equivalent rows 
  # between a and v are considered.
  result = np.searchsorted(ai.flatten(),vi.flatten(), side=side, sorter=sorter)

  # Restore the original shape, decode the searchsorted indices so they apply to the original data.
  result = result.reshape(vi.shape) - vi['row']*a.shape[1]

  return result
```

**Edit:** The timing on this approach is abysmal!

```
In [21]: %timeit searchsorted_2d(a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 92.5 ms per loop
```

You would be better off just just using `map` over the array:

```
In [22]: %timeit np.array(list(map(np.searchsorted,a,b)))
100 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop
```

For integer data, @Divakar's approach is still the fastest:

```
In [23]: %timeit searchsorted2d(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.26 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that @Divakar's solution needs the two following notes (I can't add comment because of reputation):

1. This is a computational (vectorization) optimization, **not an algorithmic one**. Meaning that there is no complexity gain in the theoretical sense.
2. It is in fact **slower** in several cases, sometimes by more than 10x. For example when one uses shape `(20, 10000)` instead of `(10000,20)`, when `b.shape[1]` is much smaller than `a.shape[1]` or when there is too much data, making it memory inefficient to work on one very long ravelled line.