# vectorizing numpy bincount

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array., `A`  I want to apply `np.bincount()` to each column of the matrix `A` to generate another 2d array `B` that is composed of the bincounts of each column of the original matrix `A`.

My problem is that np.bincount() is a function that takes a 1d array-like.  It's not an array method like `B = A.max(axis=1)` for example.

Is there a more pythonic/numpythic way to generate this `B` array other than a nasty for-loop?

```
import numpy as np

states = 4
rows = 8
cols = 4

A = np.random.randint(0,states,(rows,cols))
B = np.zeros((states,cols))

for x in range(A.shape[1]):
    B[:,x] =  np.bincount(A[:,x])
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the same philosophy as in [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862/3293881), here's a vectorized approach -

```
m = A.shape[1]    
n = A.max()+1
A1 = A + (n*np.arange(m))
out = np.bincount(A1.ravel(),minlength=n*m).reshape(m,-1).T
```

Comment: This solution is really brilliant! Just in case anyone wants to do bincount for each row like me, here is the modified code:
`m = A.shape[0]
n = A.max()+1
A1 = A + (n\*np.arange(m).reshape(m,1))
out = np.bincount(A1.ravel(),minlength=n\*m).reshape(-1,n)`

Comment: @LalaLa Yeah, there's a separate and detailed Q&A for that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256279/.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html), which will allow you to apply a 1D-method (in this case `np.bincount`) to 1D slices of a higher dimensional array:

```
import numpy as np

states = 4
rows = 8
cols = 4

A = np.random.randint(0,states,(rows,cols))
B = np.zeros((states,cols))

B = np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, axis=0, arr=A)
```

You'll have to be careful, though. This (as well as your suggested `for`-loop) only works if the output of `np.bincount` has the right shape. If the maximum state is not present in one or multiple columns of your array `A`, the output will not have a smaller dimensionality and thus, the code will file with a `ValueError`.

Comment: Note that apply_along_axis is just syntactic sugar for a for-loop, and has the same performance characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

This solution using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) is fully vectorized, thus does not include any python loops behind the scenes. Also, there are no restrictions on the input; not every column needs to contain the same set of unique values.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
rowidx, colidx = np.indices(A.shape)
(bin, col), B = npi.count_table(A.flatten(), colidx.flatten())
```

This gives an alternative (sparse) representation of the same result, which may be much more appropriate if the B array does indeed contain many zeros:

```
(bin, col), count = npi.count((A.flatten(), colidx.flatten()))
```

Note that apply_along_axis is just syntactic sugar for a for-loop, and has the same performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility:

```
import numpy as np


def bincount_columns(x, minlength=None):
    nbins = x.max() + 1
    if minlength is not None:
        nbins = max(nbins, minlength)
    ncols = x.shape[1]
    count = np.zeros((nbins, ncols), dtype=int)
    colidx = np.arange(ncols)[None, :]
    np.add.at(count, (x, colidx), 1)
    return count
```

For example,

```
In [110]: x
Out[110]: 
array([[4, 2, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 4, 4],
       [4, 3, 4, 4],
       [0, 2, 4, 0],
       [4, 1, 2, 1],
       [4, 2, 4, 3]])

In [111]: bincount_columns(x)
Out[111]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 3, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 2],
       [5, 0, 4, 2]])

In [112]: bincount_columns(x, minlength=7)
Out[112]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 3, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 2],
       [5, 0, 4, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```