# Best way to remove rows that have more of a certain value than a given amount (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I created an array of numbers of column size `d`, where the numbers are different combinations of `set(p)`. Next, I want to delete the rows where there are more instances of a number than there were in `p`. I can do it with a `for` loop, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

from collections import Counter

p = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5]
assert (len(set(p)) != 1)
cnt = Counter(p)
pos = np.array(list(it.product(set(p), repeat=d)))
ds = []
for i in range(len(pos)):
    for j, k in cnt.items():
        if len(np.where(pos[i] == j)[0]) > k:
            ds.append(i)
pos = np.delete(pos, ds, axis=0)
```

I am looking for a faster way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive integers, we can make use of `bincount`. So, we will use [`2D` bincount solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/) to get the binned counts per row in `pos` and compare against the binned counts for `p` and use that mask to select valid rows off `pos`, like so -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/ @Divakar
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)

pos_out = pos[(bincount2D_vectorized(pos)>np.bincount(p)).any(1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I am still working on understanding it. Only thing is, you have the opposite output as I expected. In your code, pos_out are the rows from pos that I expect to be deleted. What do you recommend to edit to make this happen?

Comment: @JamesCarter Invert the mask : `pos[~(bincount2D_vectorized(pos)>np.bincount(p)).any(1)]`.