# Numpy, change array's row value , each row satisfy a special condition

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array, it has huge number of rows(lager than 5000).

For the sake of simplicity，assume A is a simple version of my matrix

```
A=([[1,2,2,3,3,3],
   [[2,1,1,7,7,7],
   [[4,4,1,1,1,1]])
```

Now, A only has 3 rows:

***the 1st row has 3 values: one 1, two 2,three 3.***

***the 2nd row has 3 values, one 2, two 1,three 7.***

***the last row has 2 values, two 4, four 1.***

now I can easily find the majority value for each row:

1st is 3, 2nd is 7, 3rd is 1. (means my code already find each rows majority value and store them as [3,7,1] )

what I want to do is set each row's majority value to 0.

means set

```
A=([[1,2,2,0,0,0],
   [[2,1,1,0,0,0],
   [[4,4,0,0,0,0]])
```

A is just a simple instance.My matrix has huge number of rows.

So, how to do this thing more easily and efficiently?

I don't want to write a for loop to set the value for each row.

(means i can do A[0,A[0,:]==3]=0, A[1,A[1,:]==7]=0, A[2,A[2,:]==1]=0,but this is too complicated)

what I want is a form like this:

```
A[:,A[:,:]==[3,7,1]]=0
```

but numpy doesn't has this ability.

Can any one give me an efficient method for this? thank u very much!!!

For more generally situation, If I want to set each rows 1st biggest value to 0, 2nd biggest value to -1, 3rd biggest(if exist) value to -2 ...., how to do this?

means set:

```
A=([[-2,-1,-1,0,0,0],
   [[-2,-1,-1,0,0,0],
   [[-1,-1,0,0,0,0]])
```

Comment: Can you remove the general situation part from this question, as its already covered in your newer question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Using `2D bincount` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/ @Divakar
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)

A[A==bincount2D_vectorized(A).argmax(1)[:,None]] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: A
Out[16]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7],
       [4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [17]: A[A==bincount2D_vectorized(A).argmax(1)[:,None]] = 0

In [18]: A
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

**Approach #2**

Using [`2D mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674754/) efficiently -

```
A[A==mode(A.T,axis=0)[0][:,None]] = 0
```

Alternatively, from the same Q&A, we can use Scipy -

```
from scipy import stats

A[A==stats.mode(A.T)[0][0][:,None]] = 0
```

Comment: thanks a lot,I tried your approach A, it works!!!, another question:  this method can only change the majority value( you use argmax).  If I want set the biggest value to 0, and set the 2nd biggest value to -1, 3rd biggest value to -2  ...... how to do this?

Comment: @zeekzhen Think that would suit better as a new question as the solution would be entirely different. Can you post a new one?