# How to delete rows having same value in more than 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I  have below  Data Frame.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   4   9   4   6   9   8
2   2   2   2   2   5   9
2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   6   9   5   4   4   5
2   8   1   9   5   8   9
2   2   2   5   6   3   6
```

I need output as below:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   4   9   4   6   9   8
2   6   9   5   4   4   5
2   8   1   9   5   8   9
2   2   2   5   6   3   6
```

It means `rows having more than three columns as same value` should be deleted.
We can see in the Second and Third rows are having 5 and 7 columns as same value respectively .  We need to delete those rows.

Could any please help me.

Comment: `same value in more than 3 columns` - in sequence or any order?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `numpy` or `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut Well pandas dataframes have NumPy array as the underlying data. So NumPy might be relevant. Also, for performance it's useful.

Comment: @Divakar..Any order.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a naïve Pandas loop via [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
def max_count(s):
    return s.value_counts().values[0]

res = df[df.apply(max_count, axis=1).le(3)]

print(res)

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  1  4  9  4  6  9  8
3  2  6  9  5  4  4  5
4  2  8  1  9  5  8  9
5  2  2  2  5  6  3  6
```

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

For dataframe with `ints`, here's a vectorized one with `bincount` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/ @Divakar
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)

out = df[(bincount2D_vectorized(df.values)<=3).all(1)]
```

Sample output -

```
In [563]: df[(bincount2D_vectorized(df.values)<=3).all(1)]
Out[563]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  1  4  9  4  6  9  8
3  2  6  9  5  4  4  5
4  2  8  1  9  5  8  9
5  2  2  2  5  6  3  6
```

Comment: Is there an approach #2? I'm interested :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set which has only unique values. If a row has 3 equal values, then
len(set(row)) = len(row) - 2.
Iterate over the dataframe to find those rows and store their indexes.

```
indexes_to_remove = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if len(set(row)) < len(row) - 2:
        indexes_to_remove.append(index)
```

Then you can remove them safely.