# Major vote by column?

Tags: python, numpy, vote

I have a 20x20 2D array, from which I want to get for every column the value with the highest count of occurring (excluding zeros) i.e. the value that receives the major vote.

I can do that for a single column like this :

```
 : np.unique(p[:,0][p[:,0] != 0],return_counts=True)
 : (array([ 3, 21], dtype=int16), array([1, 3]))

 : nums, cnts = np.unique(p[:,0][ p[:,0] != 0 ],return_counts=True)
 : nums[cnts.argmax()]
 : 21
```

Just for completeness, we can extend the earlier proposed method to a loop-based solution for 2D arrays -

```
# p is 2D input array
for i in range(p.shape[1]):
    nums, cnts = np.unique(p[:,i][ p[:,i] != 0 ],return_counts=True)
    output_per_col = nums[cnts.argmax()]
```

How do I do that for all columns w/o using for loop ?

Comment: Are those all positive numbers in it?

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "numpy vector usage", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: yes they are all positive

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`bincount2D_vectorized`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/) to get binned counts per col, where the bins would be each integer. Then, simply slice out from the second count onwards (as the first count would be for `0`) and get `argmax`, add `1` (to compensate for the slicing). That's our desired output.

Hence, the solution shown as a sample case run -

```
In [116]: p # input array
Out[116]: 
array([[4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
       [3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3],
       [4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2],
       [3, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 4],
       [4, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1],
       [2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2],
       [0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 2, 4]])

In [117]: bincount2D_vectorized(p.T)[:,1:].argmax(1)+1
Out[117]: array([3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2])
```

That transpose is needed because `bincount2D_vectorized` gets us 2D bincounts per row. Thus, for an alternative problem of getting ranks per row, simply skip that transpose.

Also, feel free to explore other options in that linked Q&A to get `2D-bincounts`.