# Exclude zeros in collections.Counter in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, counter

Is there a way that `collections.Counter` doesn't count/ignores a given value (here 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

idx = np.random.randint(4, size=(100,100))
most_common = np.zeros(100)
num_most_common = np.zeros(100)

for i in range(100):
    most_common[i], num_most_common[i] = Counter(idx[i, :]).most_common(1)[0]
```

So if `0` is the most common value it should give the second most common value. In addition, is there a way to avoid the for loop in this case?

Comment: just take the top 2 most common, and then the 2nd one if the first one is `0`

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I will mark it as solved in a moment. In addition: Is it possible to generalize this for higher dimensions?

Comment: @clearseplex Higher dimensions as in 3D and higher?

Comment: @Divakar Yes for example a 3D input array

Comment: @clearseplex At least for my solution, you can use `idx.reshape(-1,idx.shape[-1])`  as the input in place of `idx`. Solution stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive numbers, we can use [`vectorized-bincount - bincount2D_vectorized`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/) -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/ @Divakar
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)

# Get binned counts per row, with each number representing a bin 
c = bincount2D_vectorized(idx)

# Skip the first element, as that represents counts for 0s.
# Get most common element and count per row
most_common = c[:,1:].argmax(1)+1
num_most_common = c[:,1:].max(1)
# faster : num_most_common = c[np.arange(len(most_common)),most_common]
```

For generic int numbers, we could extend like so -

```
s = idx.min()
c = bincount2D_vectorized(idx-s)
c[:,-s] = 0
most_common = c.argmax(1)
num_most_common = c[np.arange(len(most_common)),most_common]
most_common += s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, using a generator to only count something if it is not 0.

```
most_common = np.array([Counter(x for x in r if x).most_common(1)[0][0] for r in idx])
num_most_common = np.array([Counter(x for x in r if x).most_common(1)[0][1] for r in idx])
```

or even

```
count = np.array([Counter(x for x in r if x).most_common(1)[0] for r in idx])
most_common = count[:,0]
num_most_common = count[:,1]
```

Comment: No need for the list-comp, a generator is enough: `Counter(x for x in idx[i] if x)`