# Intersect between 1D ary and every row in 2D ary ? Overlap Count?

Tags: python, numpy, count, overlap

You can use numpy.intersect1d(a1,a2) and then the docs provide an option to intersect multiple arrays :

> reduce(np.intersect1d, ([1, 3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1], [6, 3, 4, 2]))

What I want to do is to find the intersection between a 1D array and every row in the corresponding 2D array.

**Or better** yet just the COUNT of the overlapping elements in every row.

I know I can do that with intersect1d() and a  loop, but it will be too **slow**.

How can we count the overlapping elements in every row the **numpy-way** ?

---

Ex:

```
In [59]: a2 = np.random.choice(np.arange(0,100),(10,5), replace=False)

In [60]: a2
Out[60]: 
array([[50,  5, 25, 40, 19],  1
       [43, 37, 21, 55, 11],  0
       [16, 49,  6, 86, 96],  0
       [80, 66, 87, 51, 64],  0
       [42,  7, 20, 24, 74],  1
       [92, 63, 75, 54, 90],  2
       [ 9, 91, 88, 85, 22],  0
       [ 4, 65, 97, 93, 53],  0
       [18,  0, 57, 71, 76],  0
       [94,  1, 77, 89, 45]]) 0

In [61]: a1 = np.random.choice(np.arange(0,100),5, replace=False)


In [63]: a1
Out[63]: array([63, 54, 20, 60, 25])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply get the count of common elements per row, we can get a mask of matches with `np.isin` and then just the count per row -

```
np.isin(arr2D,arr1D).sum(axis=1)
```

If you want to count each unique element only once in case of duplicate occurences per row and if input elements are positive numbers, we need few more steps -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/ @Divakar
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)

count = (bincount2D_vectorized(np.isin(arr2D,arr1D)*arr2D)[:,1:]!=0).sum(1)
```

Comment: will this  handle the case where the values are in different columns.. f.e.[1,2,3] [3,2,1] is overlap of 3

Comment: there will be no duplicates in the same row, all positive too

Comment: can u decipher this :), lookin also in your other post