# Block reduce (downsample) 3D array with mode function

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image, downsampling

I would like to downsample a 3d array by taking the most frequent value (mode) of the original values. After some research, I found the `block_reduce` function in `skimage` library. For example, if I wanted like to take the average of the block, I can do it easily:

```
from skimage.measure import block_reduce
image = np.arange(4*4*4).reshape(4, 4, 4)
new_image = block_reduce(image, block_size=(2,2,2), func=np.mean, cval=np.mean(grades))
```

In my case, I want to pass the func argument a mode function. However, numpy doesn't have a mode function. According to the documentation, the passed function should accept 'axis' as an argument. I tried some workarounds such as writing my own function and combining `np.unique` and `np.argmax`, as well as passing `scipy.stats.mode` as the function. All of them failed.

I wrote some nested for loops to do this but it's way too slow with large arrays. Is there an easy way to do this? I don't necessarily need to use sci-kit image library.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the assumption that the input image shape is divisible by `block_size`, i.e. corresponding shape dimensions are divisible by each size parameter of `block_size`.

So, as pre-processing, we need to make blocks out off the input `image`, like so -

```
def blockify(image, block_size):
    shp = image.shape
    out_shp = [s//b for s,b in zip(shp, block_size)]
    reshape_shp = np.c_[out_shp,block_size].ravel()
    nC = np.prod(block_size)
    return image.reshape(reshape_shp).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5).reshape(-1,nC)
```

Next up, for our specific case of `mode` finding, we will use [`bincount2D_vectorized`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/) alongwith `argmax` -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/ @Divakar
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)

out = bincount2D_vectorized(blockify(image, block_size=(2,2,2))).argmax(1)
```

Alternatively, we can use [`n-dim mode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674754/) -

```
out = mode(blockify(image, block_size=(2,2,2)), axis=1)[0]
```

Finally, if the initial assumption of divisibility doesn't hold true, we need to pad with the appropriate pad value. For the same, we can use `np.pad`, as part of the `blockify` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly. I didn't completely understand how the line `return image.reshape(reshape_shp).transpose(0,2,4,1,3,5).reshape(-1,nC)` works. Where did those numbers come from in the transpose function?

Comment: @user2847666 We are basically reshaping to split each axis into two, then transposing axes to bring the blocks in contiguous memory locations. This should help get some understanding into those concepts - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47978032/.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scipy.stats.mode` naively doesn't work because [`scipy.stats.mode` returns a tuple](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) (mode, count).

So all you need is a simple wrapper that takes the first return value:

```
from skimage.measure import block_reduce
from scipy.stats import mode

def mode_wrapper(x, axis):
    return mode(x, axis)[0]

new_image = block_reduce(image, block_size=(2,2,2), func=mode_wrapper)
```

Note though the [*callable* passed to `func` should implement an `axis` parameter](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.block_reduce).