# 2D Vectorization of unique values per row with condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the array and function definition shown:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2, 2, 5, 6, 2, 5],
              [1, 5, 8, 9, 9, 1],
              [0, 4, 2, 3, 7, 9],
              [1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1],
              [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
              [3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6],
              [0, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4],
              [3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3]])

def grpCountSize(arr, grpCount, grpSize):    
    count = [np.unique(row, return_counts=True)  for row in arr]
    valid = [np.any(np.count_nonzero(row[1] == grpSize) == grpCount) for row in count]
    return valid
```

The point of the function is to return the rows of array `a` that have exactly `grpCount` groups of elements that each hold exactly `grpSize` identical elements.

For example:

```
# which rows have exactly 1 group that holds exactly 2 identical elements?
out = a[grpCountSize(a, 1, 2)]
```

As expected, the code outputs `out = [[2, 2, 5, 6, 2, 5], [3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3]]`.
The 1st output row has exactly 1 group of 2 (ie: 5,5), while the 2nd output row also has exactly 1 group of 2 (ie: 7,7).

Similarly:

```
# which rows have exactly 2 groups that each hold exactly 3 identical elements?
out = a[grpCountSize(a, 2, 3)]
```

This produces `out = [[3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6]]`,  because only this row has exactly 2 groups each holding exactly 3 elements  (ie: 3,3,3   and   6,6,6)

**PROBLEM:  My actual arrays have just 6 columns, but they can have many millions of rows.  The code works perfectly as intended, but it is VERY SLOW for long arrays.   Is there a way to speed this up?**

Comment: The big speedup in `numpy` comes from applying compiled methods to the whole array.  Your code has to work row by row; if you can't figure out a way of working with multiple rows at one, you stuck with trying to speed up that row-by-row operation.  I suspect you can apply the `unique` and `count` operations together to one row, but have no sense whether than will improve times compared to the current 2 loops.  The other option is use `numba`, but I won't explore that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.unique` sorts the array which makes it less efficient for your purpose. Use `np.bincount` and that way you most likely will save some time(depending on your array shape and values in the array). You also will not need `np.any` anymore:

```
def grpCountSize(arr, grpCount, grpSize):    
    count = [np.bincount(row) for row in arr]
    valid = [np.count_nonzero(row == grpSize) == grpCount for row in count]
    return valid
```

Another way that might even save more time is using same number of bins for all rows and create one array:

```
def grpCountSize(arr, grpCount, grpSize):
    m = arr.max()
    count = np.stack([np.bincount(row, minlength=m+1) for row in arr])
    return (count == grpSize).sum(1)==grpCount
```

Another yet upgrade is to use [vectorized 2D bin count from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/4975981). For example (note that Numba solutions tested in the post above is faster. I just provided the numpy solution for example. You can replace the function with any of the suggested ones in the post linked above):

```
def grpCountSize(arr, grpCount, grpSize):
    count = bincount2D_vectorized(arr)
    return (count == grpSize).sum(1)==grpCount
#from the post above
def bincount2D_vectorized(a):    
    N = a.max()+1
    a_offs = a + np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]*N
    return np.bincount(a_offs.ravel(), minlength=a.shape[0]*N).reshape(-1,N)
```

output of all solutions above:

```
a[grpCountSize2(a, 1, 2)]
#array([[2, 2, 5, 6, 2, 5],
#       [3, 3, 7, 7, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: If you just want to use Numba without getting into its details, simply replace `bincount2D_vectorized` with any Numba functions in the link provided.