# weighted numpy bincount for 2D IDs array and 1D weights

Tags: python, binning, weighted, numpy-indexed

I am using numpy_indexed for applying a vectorized numpy bincount, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi
rowidx, colidx = np.indices(index_tri.shape)
(cols, rows), B = npi.count((index_tri.flatten(), rowidx.flatten()))
```

where `index_tri` is the following matrix:

```
index_tri = np.array([[ 0,  0,  0,  7,  1,  3],
       [ 1,  2,  2,  9,  8,  9],
       [ 3,  1,  1,  4,  9,  1],
       [ 5,  6,  6, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 7,  8,  9,  4,  3,  3],
       [ 3,  8,  6,  3,  8,  6],
       [ 4,  3,  3,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 10, 10,  5,  6,  6],
       [ 4,  9,  1,  3,  1,  1],
       [ 9,  8,  9,  1,  2,  2]])
```

Then I map the binned values in the corresponding position of the following initialized matrix `m`:

```
m = np.zeros((10,11))
m 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

m[rows, cols] = B
m
array([[3., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 2., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 3., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 0.]])
```

However, this considers that the weight of each value in `index_tri` per column is 1. Now if I have a weights array, providing a corresponding weight value per column in `index_tri` instead of 1:

`weights = np.array([0.7, 0.8, 1.5, 0.6, 0.5, 1.9])`

how to apply a weighted bincount so that my output matrix `m` becomes as follows:

```
array([[3., 0.5, 0., 1.9, 0., 0., 0., 0.6, 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0.7, 2.3, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 2.5, 0.],
       [0., 4.2, 0., 0.7, 0.6, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.7, 2.3, 0., 0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2.4, 0.6, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.8, 1.5, 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2.3, 0., 0., 2.4, 0., 1.3, 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2.3, 0.7, 0., 0., 0.6, 0.5, 1.9, 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.6, 2.4, 0., 0., 0., 3.],
       [0., 3.9, 0., 0.6, 0.7, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.8, 0.],
       [0., 0.6, 2.4, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.8, 2.2, 0.]])
```

any idea?

---

By using a `for` loop and the numpy `bincount()` I could solve it as follows:

```
for i in range(m.shape[0]):
   m[i, :] = np.bincount(index_tri[i, :], weights=weights, minlength=m.shape[1])
```

I am trying to adapt the vectorized provided solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046212/1476932) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/1476932) respectively but I cannot figure out what the `ix2D` variable corresponds to in the first link. Could someone elaborate a bit if possible.

---

Update (solution):

Based on the @Divakar's solution below, here is an updated version where it takes an extra input parameter in case that your indices input matrix does not cover the full range of the output initialized matrix:

```
    def bincount2D(id_ar_2D, weights_1D, sz=None):
        # Inputs : 2D id array, 1D weights array

        # Extent of bins per col
        if sz == None:
            n = id_ar_2D.max() + 1
            N = len(id_ar_2D)
        else:
            n = sz[1]
            N = sz[0]

        # add offsets to the original values to be used when we apply raveling later on
        id_ar_2D_offsetted = id_ar_2D + n * np.arange(N)[:, None]

        # Finally use bincount with those 2D bins as flattened and with
        # flattened b as weights. Reshaping is needed to add back into "a".
        ids = id_ar_2D_offsetted.ravel()
        W = np.tile(weights_1D, N)
        return np.bincount(ids, W, minlength=n * N).reshape(-1, n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256361/) -

```
def bincount2D(id_ar_2D, weights_1D):
    # Inputs : 2D id array, 1D weights array
    
    # Extent of bins per col
    n = id_ar_2D.max()+1
    
    N = len(id_ar_2D)
    id_ar_2D_offsetted = id_ar_2D + n*np.arange(N)[:,None]
    
    # Finally use bincount with those 2D bins as flattened and with
    # flattened b as weights. Reshaping is needed to add back into "a".
    ids = id_ar_2D_offsetted.ravel()
    W = np.tile(weights_1D,N)
    return np.bincount(ids, W, minlength=n*N).reshape(-1,n)

out = bincount2D(index_tri, weights)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured out that in `id_ar_2D_offseted` you were offsetting the initial values of matrix `id_ar_2D` to cover the 2D dimension. However, you have already answered it ;-). I've updated my answer also with a solution where I pass an extra parameters in case that the input indices matrix (its values) does not follow the exact size of an already initialized output matrix.