# Sample a random index from each column of a 2d array of probability mass functions

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have a 2d array called `pmf` where each column is a probability mass function. I would like to sample one row index per column according to the respective probability mass function.  I currently have

```
[np.random.choice(range(len(pmf.T[i])), 1, p=pmf.T[i])[0] for i in xrange(len(pmf.T))]
```

Is there a cleaner numpy way?

As an example:

```
pmf = [[0.1215122141454291, 0.02526931631702081], 
       [0.44580918821894255, 0.23465429357912862],
       [0.13924078748403307, 0.7311930810111874], 
       [0.2934378101515954, 0.008883309092663008]]
```

Then the output could be:

```
[3, 2]
```

Comment: Please share an input 2d array and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Does the given sample work on the listed code?

Comment: @Divakar Are you asking if the code works? It works for me after my latest edit.

Comment: It works now after the edit :)

Comment: Based on the linked dup target, use : `(pmf.cumsum(0) > np.random.rand(pmf.shape[1])).argmax(0)`. If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you. Wouldn't searchsorted  make more sense than argmax here?  That is assuming I understand what you are doing.

Comment: From my experience, `argmax()` is quite fast. `searchsorted` could be used as well, but that would involve few more steps to have a vectorized solution. One such method would be something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862/3293881

Comment: Some nice functionality for this here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_discrete.html#scipy.stats.rv_discrete