# Efficiently calculate histogram of a 3D numpy array along an axis with different bin edges

Tags: performance, numpy, tensorflow, gpu, histogram

#### Problem description

I have a 3D numpy array, denoted as `data`, of shape N x R x C, i.e. N samples, R rows and C columns. I would like to obtain histograms along column for each combination of sample and row. However bin edges (see argument `bins` in [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)), of fixed length S, will be different at different rows but are shared across samples. Consider this example for illustration, for the 1st sample (`data[0]`), bin edge sequence for its 1st row is different from that for its 2nd row, but is the same as that for the 1st row from the 2nd sample (`data[1]`). Thus all the bin edge sequences are stored in a 2D numpy array of shape R x S, denoted as `bin_edges`.

My question is how to efficiently calculate the histograms?

#### A working but slow solution

Using `numpy.histogram`, I was able to come up with a working but fairly slow solution as shown in the below code snippet

````
```
Get dummy data

    N: number of samples
    R: number of rows (or kernels)
    C: number of columns (or pixels)
    S: number of bins
```
import numpy as np

N, R, C, S = 100, 50, 1000, 10
data = np.random.randn(N, R, C)

# for each row/kernel, pool pixels of all samples
poolsamples = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1).reshape(R, -1)
# use quantiles as bin edges
percentiles = np.linspace(0, 100, num=(S + 1))
bin_edges = np.transpose(np.percentile(poolsamples, percentiles, axis=1))


```
A working but slow solution of getting histograms along column
```
hist = np.empty((N, R, S))
for idx in np.arange(R):
    bin_edges_i = bin_edges[idx, :]
    counts = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda a: np.histogram(a, bins=bin_edges_i)[0],
        1, data[:, idx, :])
    hist[:, idx, :] = counts
````

#### Possible directions

- Fancy numpy reshape to avoid using for loop at all
- This problem arises from extracting low-end characteristics for each image forwarded through a trained neural network. Therefore, if the histogram extraction can be embedded in TensorFlow graph and ultimately be carried out on GPU, that would be ideal!
- I noticed a python package [fast-histogram](https://github.com/astrofrog/fast-histogram) which claims to be 7-15x faster than `numpy.histogram`. However 1d histogram function can only takes number of bins instead of actual bin positions
- [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr)?

I would love to hear any inputs! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Making use of `2D` version of `np.searchsorted` : [`searchsorted2d`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862/) -

```
def vectorized_app(data, bin_edges):
    N, R, C = data.shape
    a = np.sort(data.reshape(-1,C),1)
    b = np.repeat(bin_edges[None],N,axis=0).reshape(-1,bin_edges.shape[-1])

    idx = searchsorted2d(a,b)
    idx[:,0] = 0
    idx[:,-1] = a.shape[1]
    out = (idx[:,1:] - idx[:,:-1]).reshape(N,R,-1)
    return out
```

Runtime test -

```
In [591]: N, R, C, S = 100, 50, 1000, 10
     ...: data = np.random.randn(N, R, C)
     ...: 
     ...: # for each row/kernel, pool pixels of all samples
     ...: poolsamples = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1).reshape(R, -1)
     ...: # use quantiles as bin edges
     ...: percentiles = np.linspace(0, 100, num=(S + 1))
     ...: bin_edges = np.transpose(np.percentile(poolsamples, percentiles, axis=1))
     ...: 

In [592]: %timeit org_app(data, bin_edges)
1 loop, best of 3: 481 ms per loop

In [593]: %timeit vectorized_app(data, bin_edges)
1 loop, best of 3: 224 ms per loop

In [595]: np.allclose(org_app(data, bin_edges), vectorized_app(data, bin_edges))
Out[595]: True
```

More than `2x` speedup there.

Closer look reveals that the bottleneck with the proposed vectorized method is the sorting itself -

```
In [594]: %timeit np.sort(data.reshape(-1,C),1)
1 loop, best of 3: 194 ms per loop
```

We need this sorting to use `searchsorted`.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a while to fully understand the logic behind `searchsorted2d()`. I think the implementation is smart. I am going to give it some time to see if any faster solution will come up.

Comment: time has passed