# How to searchsorted 2D arrays for rows' insertion indices in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, search

I am searching a sorted array for the proper insertion indices of new data so that it remains sorted. Although [`searchsorted2d`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862) by @Divakar works great along column insertions, it just cannot work along rows. Is there a way to perform the same, yet along the rows?

The first idea that comes to mind is to adapt `searchsorted2d` for the desired behavior. However, that does not seem as easy as it appears. Here is my attempt at adapting it, but it still does not work when `axis` is set to `0`.

```py
import numpy as np

# By Divakar
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862
def searchsorted2d(a, b, axis=0):
    shape = list(a.shape)
    shape[axis] = 1
    max_num = np.maximum(a.max() - a.min(), b.max() - b.min()) + 1
    r = np.ceil(max_num) * np.arange(a.shape[1-axis]).reshape(shape)
    p = np.searchsorted((a + r).ravel(), (b + r).ravel()).reshape(b.shape)
    return p #- a.shape[axis] * np.arange(a.shape[1-axis]).reshape(shape)

axis = 0 # Operate along which axis?
n = 16   # vector size

# Initial array
a = np.random.rand(n).reshape((n, 1) if axis else (1, n))

insert_into_a = np.random.rand(n).reshape((n, 1) if axis else (1, n))
indices = searchsorted2d(a, insert_into_a, axis=axis)
a = np.insert(a, indices.ravel(), insert_into_a.ravel()).reshape(
              (n, -1) if axis else (-1, n))

assert(np.all(a == np.sort(a, axis=axis))), 'Failed :('
print('Success :)')
```

I expect that the assertion passes in both cases (`axis = 0` and `axis = 1`).

Comment: Original `searchsorted2d` was made to work for row-wise `searchsorted-ing`. So, that was to replicate the behavior of a loopy one - `np.searchsorted(a[i],b[i])`. If you want to make it work for `np.searchsorted(a[:,i],b[:,i])`, which I am guessing is your row-wise requirement, then simply transpose the inputs before feeding to it, so - `searchsorted2d(a.T,b.T)`. Again, this is with the original implementation of `searchsorted2d`.

Comment: @Divakar I have tried `searchsorted2d(a, b)`, `searchsorted2d(a, b).reshape(b.shape)`, `searchsorted2d(a.T, b.T).reshape(b.shape)`, and `searchsorted2d(a.T, b.T).T` both with the standard implementation and `axis = 0` with no luck! If you believe your idea shall work, can you please support it with a working snapshot?

Comment: Something like this - https://ideone.com/FquZ5h

Comment: For the transposed version - https://ideone.com/tZJgNi

Comment: @Divakar printing the indices to match the output of a loopy function is different from what I want to achieve here.
I want `i = searchsorted2d(a, b)` to return the insertion indices for making a sorted array `c = np.insert(a, i, b)`.