# NumPy - np.searchsorted for 2-D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, lexicographic

[`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) only for 1D arrays.

I have a [lexicographically sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) 2D array, meaning that 0-th row is sorted, then for same values of 0-th row corresponding elements of 1-th row are sorted too, for same values of 1-th row values of 2-th row are sorted too. In other words tuples consisting of columns are sorted.

I have some other 2D array with tuples-columns that need to be inserted into first 2D array into correct positions of columns. For 1D case `np.searchsorted` was usually used in order to find correct positions.

But for 2D array is there an alternative to `np.searchsorted`? Something analagous to how [np.lexsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) is a 2D alternative for 1D [np.argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

If no such function then can be this functionality implemented in an efficient way using existing numpy functions?

I am interested in efficient solutions for arrays of any `dtype` including `np.object_`.

One naive way to handle any `dtype` case would be to convert each column of both arrays to 1D array (or tuple) and then store these columns as another 1D array of `dtype = np.object_`. Maybe it is not that naive and could be even fast especially if columns are quite high.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588403/vectorized-searchsorted-numpy or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471109/how-to-vectorize-with-numpy-searchsorted-in-a-2d-array?

Comment: @Divakar Interesting solutions, but only suitable for numbers. And can it be solved for a general case of any `dtype` including `np.object_`?

Comment: @Divakar In fact I already had a need for searchsorted both for numbers and strings too. So your solutions work for my numbers case, but also strings search is needed.

Comment: Yeah, think those are limited to ints. Maybe consider converting to ints with `np.unique(.. return_inverse=True)`.

Comment: @Divakar Idea with `np.unique` seems to be a good solution, I'll try to code it.

Comment: Can you hash the values somehow? In fact, if you're looking for object arrays, why not just make the rows into tuples and treat it as a 1D array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually would be nice to have solution for several common types, each type probably has its own fastest solution. Like if it is any object then something like tuple or 1D array of objects should be used, maybe faster is not possible. But if it is strings than you can hash and make it faster, if it is a number then you can make it even faster by strings manipulation. In other words algorithm should be able to process any input types, but should make optimizations for some special types, like special handling of any hashable type.

Comment: @MadPhysicist BTW, I already posted a day ago [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198398/941531) which exactly uses tuples, like you suggested, hence solves most general case of any object type. The question is whether most general case of any object can be improved even futher.

Comment: @Divakar I just figured out that your solutions for numbers case are solving totally different task that I need. Your solutions are just a fast way to do 1D searchsorted for many rows, each row having unrelated data. But in my task I need same 2D generalization as `np.lexsort` does over `np.argsort`, but for `np.searchsorted`, i.e. each colunn in my 2D array is a key (tuple) and these columns are sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) same as Python sorts tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created several more advanced strategies.

Also simple strategy using `tuples` like in [another my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198398/941531) is implemented.

Timings of all solutions are measured.

Most of strategies are using `np.searchsorted` as underlying engine. To implement these advanced strategies a special wrapping class `_CmpIx` was used in order to provide custom comparison function (`__lt__`) for `np.searchsorted` call.

1. `py.tuples` strategy just converts all columns to tuples and stores them as numpy 1D array of `np.object_` dtype and then doing regular searchsorting.
2. `py.zip` uses python's zip for lazily doing same task.
3. `np.lexsort` strategy just uses `np.lexsort` in order to compare two columns lexicographically.
4. `np.nonzero` uses `np.flatnonzero(a != b)` expression.
5. `cmp_numba` uses [ahead of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) compiled numba code inside `_CmpIx` wrapper for fast lexicographically lazy comparing of two provided elements.
6. `np.searchsorted` uses standard numpy's function but is measured for 1D case only.
7. for `numba` strategy whole search algorithm is implemented from scratch using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) engine, algorithm is based on [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). There is `_py` and `_nm` variants of this algorithm, `_nm` is much faster as it uses Numba compiler, while `_py` is same algorithm but un-compiled. Also there is `_sorted` flavor which does extra optimization of array to be inserted is already sorted.
8. `view1d` - methods suggested by @MadPhysicist [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64216702/941531). Commented out them in code, because they were returning incorrect answers for most of tests for all key lengths >1, probably due to some problems of raw viewing into array.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64197530#main.py)

```
class SearchSorted2D:
    class _CmpIx:
        def __init__(self, t, p, i):
            self.p, self.i = p, i
            self.leg = self.leg_cache()[t]
            self.lt = lambda o: self.leg(self, o, False) if self.i != o.i else False
            self.le = lambda o: self.leg(self, o, True) if self.i != o.i else True
        @classmethod
        def leg_cache(cls):
            if not hasattr(cls, 'leg_cache_data'):
                cls.leg_cache_data = {
                    'py.zip': cls._leg_py_zip, 'np.lexsort': cls._leg_np_lexsort,
                    'np.nonzero': cls._leg_np_nonzero, 'cmp_numba': cls._leg_numba_create(),
                }
            return cls.leg_cache_data
        def __eq__(self, o): return not self.lt(o) and self.le(o)
        def __ne__(self, o): return self.lt(o) or not self.le(o)
        def __lt__(self, o): return self.lt(o)
        def __le__(self, o): return self.le(o)
        def __gt__(self, o): return not self.le(o)
        def __ge__(self, o): return not self.lt(o)
        @staticmethod
        def _leg_np_lexsort(self, o, eq):
            import numpy as np
            ia, ib = (self.i, o.i) if eq else (o.i, self.i)
            return (np.lexsort(self.p.ab[::-1, ia : (ib + (-1, 1)[ib >= ia], None)[ib == 0] : ib - ia])[0] == 0) == eq
        @staticmethod
        def _leg_py_zip(self, o, eq):
            for l, r in zip(self.p.ab[:, self.i], self.p.ab[:, o.i]):
                if l < r:
                    return True
                if l > r:
                    return False
            return eq
        @staticmethod
        def _leg_np_nonzero(self, o, eq):
            import numpy as np
            a, b = self.p.ab[:, self.i], self.p.ab[:, o.i]
            ix = np.flatnonzero(a != b)
            return a[ix[0]] < b[ix[0]] if ix.size != 0 else eq
        @staticmethod
        def _leg_numba_create():
            import numpy as np

            try:
                from numba.pycc import CC
                cc = CC('ss_numba_mod')
                @cc.export('ss_numba_i8', 'b1(i8[:],i8[:],b1)')
                def ss_numba(a, b, eq):
                    for i in range(a.size):
                        if a[i] < b[i]:
                            return True
                        elif b[i] < a[i]:
                            return False
                    return eq
                cc.compile()
                success = True
            except:    
                success = False
                
            if success:
                try:
                    import ss_numba_mod
                except:
                    success = False
            
            def odo(self, o, eq):
                a, b = self.p.ab[:, self.i], self.p.ab[:, o.i]
                assert a.ndim == 1 and a.shape == b.shape, (a.shape, b.shape)
                return ss_numba_mod.ss_numba_i8(a, b, eq)
                
            return odo if success else None

    def __init__(self, type_):
        import numpy as np
        self.type_ = type_
        self.ci = np.array([], dtype = np.object_)
    def __call__(self, a, b, *pargs, **nargs):
        import numpy as np
        self.ab = np.concatenate((a, b), axis = 1)
        self._grow(self.ab.shape[1])
        ix = np.searchsorted(self.ci[:a.shape[1]], self.ci[a.shape[1] : a.shape[1] + b.shape[1]], *pargs, **nargs)
        return ix
    def _grow(self, to):
        import numpy as np
        if self.ci.size >= to:
            return
        import math
        to = 1 << math.ceil(math.log(to) / math.log(2))
        self.ci = np.concatenate((self.ci, [self._CmpIx(self.type_, self, i) for i in range(self.ci.size, to)]))

class SearchSorted2DNumba:
    @classmethod
    def do(cls, a, v, side = 'left', *, vsorted = False, numba_ = True):
        import numpy as np

        if not hasattr(cls, '_ido_numba'):
            def _ido_regular(a, b, vsorted, lrt):
                nk, na, nb = a.shape[0], a.shape[1], b.shape[1]
                res = np.zeros((2, nb), dtype = np.int64)
                max_depth = 0
                if nb == 0:
                    return res, max_depth
                #lb, le, rb, re = 0, 0, 0, 0
                lrb, lre = 0, 0
                
                if vsorted:
                    brngs = np.zeros((nb, 6), dtype = np.int64)
                    brngs[0, :4] = (-1, 0, nb >> 1, nb)
                    i, j, size = 0, 1, 1
                    while i < j:
                        for k in range(i, j):
                            cbrng = brngs[k]
                            bp, bb, bm, be = cbrng[:4]
                            if bb < bm:
                                brngs[size, :4] = (k, bb, (bb + bm) >> 1, bm)
                                size += 1
                            bmp1 = bm + 1
                            if bmp1 < be:
                                brngs[size, :4] = (k, bmp1, (bmp1 + be) >> 1, be)
                                size += 1
                        i, j = j, size
                    assert size == nb
                    brngs[:, 4:] = -1

                for ibc in range(nb):
                    if not vsorted:
                        ib, lrb, lre = ibc, 0, na
                    else:
                        ibpi, ib = int(brngs[ibc, 0]), int(brngs[ibc, 2])
                        if ibpi == -1:
                            lrb, lre = 0, na
                        else:
                            ibp = int(brngs[ibpi, 2])
                            if ib < ibp:
                                lrb, lre = int(brngs[ibpi, 4]), int(res[1, ibp])
                            else:
                                lrb, lre = int(res[0, ibp]), int(brngs[ibpi, 5])
                        brngs[ibc, 4 : 6] = (lrb, lre)
                        assert lrb != -1 and lre != -1
                        
                    for ik in range(nk):
                        if lrb >= lre:
                            if ik > max_depth:
                                max_depth = ik
                            break

                        bv = b[ik, ib]
                        
                        # Binary searches
                        
                        if nk != 1 or lrt == 2:
                            cb, ce = lrb, lre
                            while cb < ce:
                                cm = (cb + ce) >> 1
                                av = a[ik, cm]
                                if av < bv:
                                    cb = cm + 1
                                elif bv < av:
                                    ce = cm
                                else:
                                    break
                            lrb, lre = cb, ce
                                
                        if nk != 1 or lrt >= 1:
                            cb, ce = lrb, lre
                            while cb < ce:
                                cm = (cb + ce) >> 1
                                if not (bv < a[ik, cm]):
                                    cb = cm + 1
                                else:
                                    ce = cm
                            #rb, re = cb, ce
                            lre = ce
                                
                        if nk != 1 or lrt == 0 or lrt == 2:
                            cb, ce = lrb, lre
                            while cb < ce:
                                cm = (cb + ce) >> 1
                                if a[ik, cm] < bv:
                                    cb = cm + 1
                                else:
                                    ce = cm
                            #lb, le = cb, ce
                            lrb = cb
                            
                        #lrb, lre = lb, re
                            
                    res[:, ib] = (lrb, lre)
                    
                return res, max_depth

            cls._ido_regular = _ido_regular
            
            import numba
            cls._ido_numba = numba.jit(nopython = True, nogil = True, cache = True)(cls._ido_regular)
            
        assert side in ['left', 'right', 'left_right'], side
        a, v = np.array(a), np.array(v)
        assert a.ndim == 2 and v.ndim == 2 and a.shape[0] == v.shape[0], (a.shape, v.shape)
        res, max_depth = (cls._ido_numba if numba_ else cls._ido_regular)(
            a, v, vsorted, {'left': 0, 'right': 1, 'left_right': 2}[side],
        )
        return res[0] if side == 'left' else res[1] if side == 'right' else res

def Test():
    import time
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(0)
    
    def round_float_fixed_str(x, n = 0):
        if type(x) is int:
            return str(x)
        s = str(round(float(x), n))
        if n > 0:
            s += '0' * (n - (len(s) - 1 - s.rfind('.')))
        return s

    def to_tuples(x):
        r = np.empty([x.shape[1]], dtype = np.object_)
        r[:] = [tuple(e) for e in x.T]
        return r
    
    searchsorted2d = {
        'py.zip': SearchSorted2D('py.zip'),
        'np.nonzero': SearchSorted2D('np.nonzero'),
        'np.lexsort': SearchSorted2D('np.lexsort'),
        'cmp_numba': SearchSorted2D('cmp_numba'),
    }
    
    for iklen, klen in enumerate([1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]):
        times = {}
        for side in ['left', 'right']:
            a = np.zeros((klen, 0), dtype = np.int64)
            tac = to_tuples(a)

            for itest in range((15, 100)[iklen == 0]):
                b = np.random.randint(0, (3, 100000)[iklen == 0], (klen, np.random.randint(1, (1000, 2000)[iklen == 0])), dtype = np.int64)
                b = b[:, np.lexsort(b[::-1])]
                
                if iklen == 0:
                    assert klen == 1, klen
                    ts = time.time()
                    ix1 = np.searchsorted(a[0], b[0], side = side)
                    te = time.time()
                    times['np.searchsorted'] = times.get('np.searchsorted', 0.) + te - ts
                    
                for cached in [False, True]:
                    ts = time.time()
                    tb = to_tuples(b)
                    ta = tac if cached else to_tuples(a)
                    ix1 = np.searchsorted(ta, tb, side = side)
                    if not cached:
                        ix0 = ix1
                    tac = np.insert(tac, ix0, tb) if cached else tac
                    te = time.time()
                    timesk = f'py.tuples{("", "_cached")[cached]}'
                    times[timesk] = times.get(timesk, 0.) + te - ts

                for type_ in searchsorted2d.keys():
                    if iklen == 0 and type_ in ['np.nonzero', 'np.lexsort']:
                        continue
                    ss = searchsorted2d[type_]
                    try:
                        ts = time.time()
                        ix1 = ss(a, b, side = side)
                        te = time.time()
                        times[type_] = times.get(type_, 0.) + te - ts
                        assert np.array_equal(ix0, ix1)
                    except Exception:
                        times[type_ + '!failed'] = 0.

                for numba_ in [False, True]:
                    for vsorted in [False, True]:
                        if numba_:
                            # Heat-up/pre-compile numba
                            SearchSorted2DNumba.do(a, b, side = side, vsorted = vsorted, numba_ = numba_)
                        
                        ts = time.time()
                        ix1 = SearchSorted2DNumba.do(a, b, side = side, vsorted = vsorted, numba_ = numba_)
                        te = time.time()
                        timesk = f'numba{("_py", "_nm")[numba_]}{("", "_sorted")[vsorted]}'
                        times[timesk] = times.get(timesk, 0.) + te - ts
                        assert np.array_equal(ix0, ix1)


                # View-1D methods suggested by @MadPhysicist
                if False: # Commented out as working just some-times
                    aT, bT = np.copy(a.T), np.copy(b.T)
                    assert aT.ndim == 2 and bT.ndim == 2 and aT.shape[1] == klen and bT.shape[1] == klen, (aT.shape, bT.shape, klen)
                    
                    for ty in ['if', 'cf']:
                        try:
                            dt = np.dtype({'if': [('', b.dtype)] * klen, 'cf': [('row', b.dtype, klen)]}[ty])
                            ts = time.time()
                            va = np.ndarray(aT.shape[:1], dtype = dt, buffer = aT)
                            vb = np.ndarray(bT.shape[:1], dtype = dt, buffer = bT)
                            ix1 = np.searchsorted(va, vb, side = side)
                            te = time.time()
                            assert np.array_equal(ix0, ix1), (ix0.shape, ix1.shape, ix0[:20], ix1[:20])
                            times[f'view1d_{ty}'] = times.get(f'view1d_{ty}', 0.) + te - ts
                        except Exception:
                            raise
                
                a = np.insert(a, ix0, b, axis = 1)
            
        stimes = ([f'key_len: {str(klen).rjust(3)}'] +
            [f'{k}: {round_float_fixed_str(v, 4).rjust(7)}' for k, v in times.items()])
        nlines = 4
        print('-' * 50 + '\n' + ('', '!LARGE!:\n')[iklen == 0], end = '')
        for i in range(nlines):
            print(',  '.join(stimes[len(stimes) * i // nlines : len(stimes) * (i + 1) // nlines]), flush = True)
            
Test()
```

outputs:

```
--------------------------------------------------
!LARGE!:
key_len:   1,  np.searchsorted:  0.0250
py.tuples_cached:  3.3113,  py.tuples: 30.5263,  py.zip: 40.9785
cmp_numba: 25.7826,  numba_py:  3.6673
numba_py_sorted:  6.8926,  numba_nm:  0.0466,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0505
--------------------------------------------------
key_len:   1,  py.tuples_cached:  0.1371
py.tuples:  0.4698,  py.zip:  1.2005,  np.nonzero:  4.7827
np.lexsort:  4.4672,  cmp_numba:  1.0644,  numba_py:  0.2748
numba_py_sorted:  0.5699,  numba_nm:  0.0005,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0020
--------------------------------------------------
key_len:   2,  py.tuples_cached:  0.1131
py.tuples:  0.3643,  py.zip:  1.0670,  np.nonzero:  4.5199
np.lexsort:  3.4595,  cmp_numba:  0.8582,  numba_py:  0.4958
numba_py_sorted:  0.6454,  numba_nm:  0.0025,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0025
--------------------------------------------------
key_len:   5,  py.tuples_cached:  0.1876
py.tuples:  0.4493,  py.zip:  1.6342,  np.nonzero:  5.5168
np.lexsort:  4.6086,  cmp_numba:  1.0939,  numba_py:  1.0607
numba_py_sorted:  0.9737,  numba_nm:  0.0050,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0065
--------------------------------------------------
key_len:  10,  py.tuples_cached:  0.6017
py.tuples:  1.2275,  py.zip:  3.5276,  np.nonzero: 13.5460
np.lexsort: 12.4183,  cmp_numba:  2.5404,  numba_py:  2.8334
numba_py_sorted:  2.3991,  numba_nm:  0.0165,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0155
--------------------------------------------------
key_len:  20,  py.tuples_cached:  0.8316
py.tuples:  1.3759,  py.zip:  3.4238,  np.nonzero: 13.7834
np.lexsort: 16.2164,  cmp_numba:  2.4483,  numba_py:  2.6405
numba_py_sorted:  2.2226,  numba_nm:  0.0170,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0160
--------------------------------------------------
key_len:  50,  py.tuples_cached:  1.0443
py.tuples:  1.4085,  py.zip:  2.2475,  np.nonzero:  9.1673
np.lexsort: 19.5266,  cmp_numba:  1.6181,  numba_py:  1.7731
numba_py_sorted:  1.4637,  numba_nm:  0.0415,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0405
--------------------------------------------------
key_len: 100,  py.tuples_cached:  2.0136
py.tuples:  2.5380,  py.zip:  2.2279,  np.nonzero:  9.2929
np.lexsort: 33.9505,  cmp_numba:  1.5722,  numba_py:  1.7158
numba_py_sorted:  1.4208,  numba_nm:  0.0871,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.0851
--------------------------------------------------
key_len: 200,  py.tuples_cached:  3.5945
py.tuples:  4.1847,  py.zip:  2.3553,  np.nonzero: 11.3781
np.lexsort: 66.0104,  cmp_numba:  1.8153,  numba_py:  1.9449
numba_py_sorted:  1.6463,  numba_nm:  0.1661,  numba_nm_sorted:  0.1651
```

As it appears from timings `numba_nm` implementation is the fastest, it outperforms next fastest (`py.zip` or `py.tuples_cached`) by `15-100x` times. And it has comparable speed (`1.85x` slower) to standard `np.searchsorted` for 1D case. Also it appeared to be that `_sorted` flavor doesn't improve situation (i.e. using information about inserted array being sorted).

`cmp_numba` method that is machine-code compiled appears to be around `1.5x` times faster on average than `py.zip` that does same algorithm but in pure python. Due to average maximum equal-key depth being around `15-18` elements numba doesn't gain much speedup here. If depth was hundreds then numba code would probably have a huge speedup.

`py.tuples_cached` strategy is faster than `py.zip` for the case of key length `<= 100`.

Also it appears to be that `np.lexsort` is in fact very slow, either it is not optimized for the case of just two columns, or it spends time doing preprocessing like splitting rows into list, or it does non-lazy lexicographical comparison, the last case is probably the real reason as lexsort slows down with key length grow.

Strategy `np.nonzero` is also non-lazy hence works slow too, and slows down with key length growth (but slows down not that fast as `np.lexsort` does).

Timings above may be not precise, because my CPU slows down cores frequency 2-2.3 times at random times whenever it is overheated, and it overheats often because it is a powerful CPU inside laptop.

Comment: Your timing includes a whole lot of stuff it really shouldn't, like key lookup in the timing dictionary

Comment: @MadPhysicist When doing timing I usually don't bother about small things that in total all take less than 1% of measured time. Same like in other questions where I included `if bool_var else` in `Do()`. And here dict lookup is just few python operations which is microseconds. While whole cycle of one test is milliseconds. But thanks, I'll correct it now and repost. BTW as I said my timings include my CPU being slown down frequently hence my timings may be even `2x` times off, and that is a bigger issue I think to bother :).

Comment: It is only important to care about tiny things included in timing only for micro-measurement like when you measure how fast is code `a + b`, when you have to run 1 million cycles. But when you have just 20 cycles within one second then all the tiny things like dict lookup or `if` condition don't mean almost anything for timing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Other stuff like `to_tuples(a)` or `np.insert(tac, ix0, tb)` should be definitely inside timings measurement because it is supporting code for search sorted, it should be always included in client's code, hence can't be un-measured.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If cause if each cycle measured would not take 50 milliseconds which is huge like in my case, but e.g. 200 nanoseconds, then definitely removing unnecessary code and using `timeit` instead of `time.time()` would be really necessary.

Comment: From a practical point of view you are of course correct. I generally tend to nitpick and make things overly-precise even when it's not warranted. :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, it is very nice to make code tidy and I like it too from time to time, especially if to make final version for public use. But for the case of speed much more impact is done (sometimes 10th magnitude) through finding a good algorithm.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Just decided to implement [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204215/941531) whole searchsorted 2D algorithm from scratch using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) module and binary search approach. It outperformed next fastest (using `zip` or `tuples`) algorithm by `15x-100x` times, and is close (`1.85x` slower) to speed of standard numpy's `np.searchsorted` for specific 1D case.

Answer (score 3):

Two things can help you here: (1) you can sort and search structured arrays, and (2) if you have finite collections that can be mapped to integers, you can use that to your advantage.

**Viewing as 1D**

Let's say you have an array of strings that you want to insert into:

```
data = np.array([['a', '1'], ['a', 'z'], ['b', 'a']], dtype=object)
```

Since arrays are never ragged, you can construct a dtype that is the size of a row:

```
dt = np.dtype([('', data.dtype)] * data.shape[1])
```

Using my shamelessly plugged answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64210754/2988730), you can view the original 2D array as 1D now:

```
view = np.ndarray(data.shape[:1], dtype=dt, buffer=data)
```

Searching can be done in a totally straightforward manner now:

```
key = np.array([('a', 'a')], dtype=dt)
index = np.searchsorted(view, key)
```

You can even find the insertion indices of incomplete elements by using the appropriate minimum values. For strings this would be `''`.

**Faster Comparison**

You may get better mileage out of the comparison if you don't have to check each field of the dtype. You can make a similar dtype with a single homogeneous field:

```
dt2 = np.dtype([('row', data.dtype, data.shape[1])])
```

Constructing the view is the same as before:

```
view = np.ndarray(data.shape[:1], dtype=dt2, buffer=data)
```

The key is done a little differently this time (another plug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64211744/2988730)):

```
key = np.array([(['a', 'a'],)], dtype=dt2)
```

The sort order imposed on objects is not correct with this method: [Sorting array of objects by row using custom dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64215263/2988730). I am leaving a reference here in case there is a fix in the linked question. Also, it is still quite useful for sorting integers.

**Integer Mapping**

If you have a finite number of objects to search, it is easier to map them to integers:

```
idata = np.empty(data.shape, dtype=int)
keys = [None] * data.shape[1]     # Map index to key per column
indices = [None] * data.shape[1]  # Map key to index per column
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    keys[i], idata[:, i] = np.unique(data[:, i], return_inverse=True)
    indices[i] = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(keys[i])}  # Assumes hashable objects

idt = np.dtype([('row', idata.dtype, idata.shape[1])])
view = idata.view(idt).ravel()
```

This only works if `data` actually contains all the possible keys in each column. Otherwise, you will have to get the forward and reverse mappings by other means. Once you have that established, setting up the keys is much simpler, and only requires `indices`:

```
key = np.array([index[k] for index, k in zip(indices, ['a', 'a'])])
```

**Further Improvements**

If the number of categories you have is eight or less, and each category has 256 or fewer elements, you can construct an even better hash by fitting everything into a single `np.uint64` element or so.

```
k = math.ceil(math.log(data.shape[1], 2))  # math.log provides base directly
assert 0 < k <= 64
idata = np.empty((data.shape[:1], k), dtype=np.uint8)
...
idata = idata.view(f'>u{k}').ravel()
```

Keys are made similarly as well:

```
key = np.array([index[k] for index, k in zip(indices, ['a', 'a'])]).view(f'>u{k}')
```

**Timing**

I've timed the methods shown here (not the other answers) using randomly shuffled strings. Key timing parameters are:

- `M`: number of rows: 10**{2, 3, 4, 5}
- `N`: number of columns: 2**{3, 4, 5, 6}
- `K`: number of elements to insert: `1, 10, M // 10`
- method: `individual_fields`, `combined_field`, `int_mapping`, `int_packing`. Functions shown below.

For the last two methods, I assume that you will pre-convert the data into the mapped dtype, but not the search keys. I am therefore passing in the converted data, but timing the conversion of the keys.

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil, log

def individual_fields(data, keys):
    dt = [('', data.dtype)] * data.shape[1]
    dview = np.ndarray(data.shape[:1], dtype=dt, buffer=data)
    kview = np.ndarray(keys.shape[:1], dtype=dt, buffer=keys)
    return np.searchsorted(dview, kview)

def combined_fields(data, keys):
    dt = [('row', data.dtype, data.shape[1])]
    dview = np.ndarray(data.shape[:1], dtype=dt, buffer=data)
    kview = np.ndarray(keys.shape[:1], dtype=dt, buffer=keys)
    return np.searchsorted(dview, kview)

def int_mapping(idata, keys, indices):
    idt = np.dtype([('row', idata.dtype, idata.shape[1])])
    dview = idata.view(idt).ravel()
    kview = np.empty(keys.shape[0], dtype=idt)
    for i, (index, key) in enumerate(zip(indices, keys.T)):
        kview['row'][:, i] = [index[k] for k in key]
    return np.searchsorted(dview, kview)

def int_packing(idata, keys, indices):
    idt = f'>u{idata.shape[1]}'
    dview = idata.view(idt).ravel()
    kview = np.empty(keys.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, (index, key) in enumerate(zip(indices, keys.T)):
        kview[:, i] = [index[k] for k in key]
    kview = kview.view(idt).ravel()
    return np.searchsorted(dview, kview)
```

The timing code:

```
from math import ceil, log
from string import ascii_lowercase
from timeit import Timer

def time(m, n, k, fn, *args):
    t = Timer(lambda: fn(*args))
    s = t.autorange()[0]
    print(f'M={m}; N={n}; K={k} {fn.__name__}: {min(t.repeat(5, s)) / s}')

selection = np.array(list(ascii_lowercase), dtype=object)
for lM in range(2, 6):
    M = 10**lM
    for lN in range(3, 6):
        N = 2**lN
        data = np.random.choice(selection, size=(M, N))
        np.ndarray(data.shape[0], dtype=[('', data.dtype)] * data.shape[1], buffer=data).sort()
        idata = np.array([[ord(a) - ord('a') for a in row] for row in data], dtype=np.uint8)
        ikeys = [selection] * data.shape[1]
        indices = [{k: i for i, k in enumerate(selection)}] * data.shape[1]
        for K in (1, 10, M // 10):
            key = np.random.choice(selection, size=(K, N))
            time(M, N, K, individual_fields, data, key)
            time(M, N, K, combined_fields, data, key)
            time(M, N, K, int_mapping, idata, key, indices)
            if N <= 8:
                time(M, N, K, int_packing, idata, key, indices)
```

The results:

*M=100 (units=us)*

```
   |                           K                           |
   +---------------------------+---------------------------+
N  |             1             |            10             |
   +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
   |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |
---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
 8 | 25.9 | 18.6 | 52.6 | 48.2 | 35.8 | 22.7 | 76.3 | 68.2 | 
16 | 40.1 | 19.0 | 87.6 |  --  | 51.1 | 22.8 | 130. |  --  |
32 | 68.3 | 18.7 | 157. |  --  | 79.1 | 22.4 | 236. |  --  |
64 | 125. | 18.7 | 290. |  --  | 135. | 22.4 | 447. |  --  |
---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

*M=1000 (units=us)*

```
   |                                         K                                         |
   +---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
N  |             1             |            10             |            100            |
   +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
   |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |
---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
 8 | 26.9 | 19.1 | 55.0 | 55.0 | 44.8 | 25.1 | 79.2 | 75.0 | 218. | 74.4 | 305. | 250. |
16 | 41.0 | 19.2 | 90.5 |  --  | 59.3 | 24.6 | 134. |  --  | 244. | 79.0 | 524. |  --  | 
32 | 68.5 | 19.0 | 159. |  --  | 87.4 | 24.7 | 241. |  --  | 271. | 80.5 | 984. |  --  |
64 | 128. | 19.7 | 312. |  --  | 168. | 26.0 | 549. |  --  | 396. | 7.78 | 2.0k |  --  |
---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

*M=10K (units=us)*

```
   |                                         K                                         |
   +---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
N  |             1             |            10             |           1000            |
   +------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
   |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |  IF  |  CF  |  IM  |  IP  |
---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
 8 | 28.8 | 19.5 | 54.5 | 107. | 57.0 | 27.2 | 90.5 | 128. | 3.2k | 762. | 2.7k | 2.1k |
16 | 42.5 | 19.6 | 90.4 |  --  | 73.0 | 27.2 | 140. |  --  | 3.3k | 752. | 4.6k |  --  |
32 | 73.0 | 19.7 | 164. |  --  | 104. | 26.7 | 246. |  --  | 3.4k | 803. | 8.6k |  --  |
64 | 135. | 19.8 | 302. |  --  | 162. | 26.1 | 466. |  --  | 3.7k | 791. | 17.k |  --  |
---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

`individual_fields` (IF) is generally fastest working method. Its complexity grows in proportion to the number of columns. Unfortunately `combined_fields` (CF) does not work for object arrays. Otherwise, it would be not only the fastest method, but also one that does not gain complexity with increasing columns.

All the techniques I thought would be faster are not, because mapping python objects to keys is slow (actual lookup of packed int arrays, for example, is much much faster than structured arrays).

**References**

Here are the additional questions I had to ask to get this code working at all:

- [View object array under different dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64210754/2988730)
- [Creating array with single structured element containing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64211744/2988730)
- [Sorting array of objects by row using custom dtype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64215263/2988730)

Comment: Regarding first section `Viewing as 1D` - how did it happen that searchsorted correctly compares elements of 1D? Because it compares 1D arrays. And `<` operation on 1D arrays gives element-wise comparison, resulting in array of same size instead of single `bool`. Lexicographical comparison producing just one bool should be done. But how searchsorted guesses that it should do `<` lexicographically? Or it does something else, not lexicographical comparison?

Comment: @Arty. It's lexicographically sorted according to the docs, unless you pass a custom sorter

Comment: Are you saying that to a new custom `dtype` created you can assign custom `<` comparison function? And by default custom `dtype` has lexicographical sorting?

Comment: @Arty. Yes. [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) docs say " The enhanced sort order is documented in [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)." `sort` says that fields in structured array are used in the order that they appear.

Comment: @Arty. My only confusion is when the dtype has a single array field, it seems to sort the pointers instead of their content, which is unexpected.

Comment: Have you compared your view1d methods results to any reference simple methods like [tuple method here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198398/941531)? I've just put your IF/CF methods into my measurement code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204215/941531) and it appears to be that your methods MOST-TIMES  return different output indexes from `np.searchsorted` for the case when key length is >1 unlike dozen of my methods which all return same result. It could be the case that numpy compares such custom types not lexicographically or there is some internal problems with raw views

Comment: @Arty. `combined_fields` unfortunately does not work right for objects, and `int_pacing` only works for `N<=8`. However, I've checked that the other methods return identical and sensible results.

Comment: @Arty. That being said, I've more than likely screwed something up. Could you walk me through an example that fails? I'll be happy to investigate.

Comment: I've tried your solutions for the case of `np.int64` so it should be simplest case when CF works also. But still getting wrong results. It could be due to me using `np.copy(a.T)` for your code. Maybe copy is not doing real copy. Because I have transposed arrays in my case, which should be transposed to match your solution, where each key is a row, not column.

Comment: @Arty. Copy is likely taking the underlying data and actually transposing it to be in C order in memory.

Comment: I've put your viewing solution into my code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64204215/941531) to make measurements. Your code is commented out by `if False:`. So this code fails in part of times, as if memory gets broken from time to time or maybe some un-stable sort order there is used.

Comment: So is it the correct way? that I'm preparing data for using your views solution by `data_for_view = np.copy(a.T)`? Or it needs some special thing like non-C ordering besides doing a copy?

Comment: Also if you're testing my code then decrease data size in expression `np.random.randint(1, (1000, 2000)[iklen == 0])` from thousands to something like `50`. Because I use really huge data there and tests are running very slow. And/Or another way to decrese test count limit in `for itest in range((15, 100)[iklen == 0])` from 15/100 to something like 3-4.

Comment: @Arty. I don't think so. I need C-contiguous data so that structures are lumped together in memory, with the first index being the row and the second being the element within the row.

Comment: Understood, probably I have un-continuous data with gaps. I'll read your article then and try to fix my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222660/discussion-between-mad-physicist-and-arty).

Answer (score 0):

Posting first naive solution that I mentioned in my question, it just converts 2D array to 1D array of `dtype = np.object_` containing original columns as Python tuples, then uses 1D `np.searchsorted`, solution works for any `dtype`. In fact this solution is not that naive, its quite fast, as measured in my other answer to current question, especially it is fast for keys lengths below 100.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFNa8MwDL37V@hWC7yQruwS2F/Yabc0FDfR1oxG9mwHnP35TO4H9LQZjCz03tOT7Jd0crxb13HyLiTgefIL2AjsFfsqWB7cVEWiQdeo1EAfkNzBHb90xkaBnEARXgVe0eTTonWu4sl6auvOoIEhLZ6udSFRnw54Z7VNJ4U2zf5MWurxeyb6IU0GakT4cAEIRi7U6M9j0tnAgzjYPJbONXY3xTQHLsJK2WvHm/sSRk66NrAzoLcSn3eI6vgfavsiKGUNFGSb28YU/JlylFVpyZunbYfdxWouVnXBih/lQ5EScO@4t4lYri65lTafpO1tDqG3b45l5KZMhLKxzZ73vBGdy3PzYOC@@Ood/2oZyYb@VCzKp12quK6/)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

def to_obj(x):
    res = np.empty((x.shape[0],), dtype = np.object_)
    res[:] = [tuple(np.squeeze(e, 0)) for e in np.split(x, x.shape[0], axis = 0)]
    return res

a = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 23))
b = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 15))

a, b = [x[:, np.lexsort(x[::-1])] for x in (a, b)]

print(np.concatenate((np.arange(a.shape[1])[None, :], a)), '\n\n', b, '\n')

a, b = [to_obj(x.T) for x in (a, b)]

print(np.searchsorted(a, b))
```