# View object array under different dtype

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I would like to view an object array with a dtype that encapsulates entire rows:

```
data = np.array([['a', '1'], ['a', 'z'], ['b', 'a']], dtype=object)
dt = np.dtype([('x', object), ('y', object)])
data.view(dt)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.
```

I have tried the following workarounds:

```
dt2 = np.dtype([('x', np.object, 2)])
data.view()
data.view(np.uint8).view(dt)
data.view(np.void).view(dt)
```

All cases result in the same error. Is there some way to view an object array with a different dtype?

I have also tried a more general approach (this is for reference, since it's functionally identical to what's shown above):

```
dt = np.dtype(','.join(data.dtype.char * data.shape[1]))
dt2 = np.dtype([('x', data.dtype, data.shape[1])])
```

Comment: Note that the error is raised by `np.core._internal._view_is_safe(oldtype, newtype)`.  The condition is that either `oldtype` or `newtype` has an `object` field.  My guess is that the developer(s) decided to treat all such conversions as unsafe, rather than deal with edge cases that might or might not be safe.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can always force a view of a buffer using [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
view = np.array(data, dtype=dt, copy=not data.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'])
```

While this is a quick and dirty approach, the data gets copied in this case, and `dt2` does not get applied correctly:

```
>>> print(view.base)
None
>>> np.array(data, dtype=dt2, copy=not data.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'])
array([[(['a', 'a'],), (['1', '1'],)],
       [(['a', 'a'],), (['z', 'z'],)],
       [(['b', 'b'],), (['a', 'a'],)]], dtype=[('x', 'O', (2,))])
```

For a more correct approach (in some circumstances), you can use the raw [`np.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) constructor:

```
real_view = np.ndarray(data.shape[:1], dtype=dt2, buffer=data)
```

This makes a true view of the data:

```
>>> real_view
array([(['a', '1'],), (['a', 'z'],), (['b', 'a'],)], dtype=[('x', 'O', (2,))])
>>> real_view.base is data
True
```

As shown, this only works when the data has C-contiguous rows.