# Creating array with single structured element containing an array

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

I have a dtype like this:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype([('x', object, 3)])
>>> dt
dtype([('x', 'O', (3,))])
```

One field named 'x', containing three pointers. I would like to construct an array with a single element of this type:

```
>>> a = np.array([(['a', 'b', 'c'])], dtype=dt)
>>> b = np.array([(np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object))], dtype=dt)
>>> c = np.array((['a', 'b', 'c']), dtype=dt)
>>> d = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=dt)

>>> e = np.array([([['a', 'b', 'c']])], dtype=dt)
```

All five of these statements yield the same incorrect result:

```
array([[(['a', 'a', 'a'],), (['b', 'b', 'b'],), (['c', 'c', 'c'],)]],
      dtype=[('x', 'O', (3,))])
```

If I try to drop the inner list/array, I get an error:

```
>>> f = np.array([('a', 'b', 'c')], dtype=dt)
ValueError: could not assign tuple of length 3 to structure with 1 fields.
```

Same error happens for

```
>>> g = np.array(('a', 'b', 'c'), dtype=dt)
```

I've run out of possible combinations to try. The result I am looking for is

```
 array([(['a', 'b', 'c'],)], dtype=[('x', 'O', (3,))])
```

How do I create an array that has one element of the specified dtype?

So far, the only approach that I've found is manual assignment:

```
z = np.empty(1, dtype=dt)
z['x'][0, :] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

OR

```
z[0]['x'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This seems like an unnecessary workaround for something that `np.array` ought to be able to handle out of the box.

Comment: Maybe should be `dt = np.dtype([('x', object, 3)])`?

Comment: It looks like some of your attempts to create a tuple of length 1 are missing the required trailiing comma.  Try `a = np.array([(['a', 'b', 'c'],)], dtype=dt)`

Comment: I also just came across same task today, the only way I found out is first to create empty/zeros array of np.object_ dtype and then to assign necessary elements to it.

Comment: @Arty. I came across this trying to answer your earlier question :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. I fixed the dtype. I copied it into my console, realized my mistake, and only copied the correct output back :)

Comment: @Arty. You may also find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64210754/2988730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [44]: dt = np.dtype([('x', object, 3)])   # corrected
In [45]: dt
Out[45]: dtype([('x', 'O', (3,))])
In [46]: np.empty(3, dt)
Out[46]: 
array([([None, None, None],), ([None, None, None],),
       ([None, None, None],)], dtype=[('x', 'O', (3,))])
In [47]: np.array([(['a','b','c'],)], dt)
Out[47]: array([(['a', 'b', 'c'],)], dtype=[('x', 'O', (3,))])
```

Input formatting should match output formatting.

```
In [48]: arr = np.empty(3, dt)
In [49]: arr['x']
Out[49]: 
array([[None, None, None],
       [None, None, None],
       [None, None, None]], dtype=object)
In [50]: arr['x'][0]
Out[50]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [51]: arr['x'][0] = ['a','b','c']
In [52]: arr
Out[52]: 
array([(['a', 'b', 'c'],), ([None, None, None],), ([None, None, None],)],
      dtype=[('x', 'O', (3,))])
```

Comment: Got it. Missing comma. I'm almost tempted to close as a typo but the answer is good.

Comment: I think you're missing the assignment of `empty(...)` to `arr,`