# Searching 1d array in 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, numpy, indexing

Say I have a massive 2D Database shaped `(1.2mil, 6)`.

I want to find the index of a 1D array `(1, 6)` in the `big_DB`. I actually have 64 of these vectors to search for at a time, shaped `(64, 6)`.

Here's my code:

```
for data in range(64): # I have 64 1d arrays to find
    self.idx = np.where((big_DB == arrays[data]).all(axis=1))
```

This takes 0.043 sec (for all 64 arrays). Is there a faster method to do this? My project will call the search function over 40,000 times.

Edit)
The big_DB is the result of itertools.product, unique in row, float.

Comment: What dtype do you have?

Comment: Here's a related post I made: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64215263/2988730. Searching is easier than sorting. Will post once you've clarified a few things.

Comment: Is `big_DB` sorted? Can it be? Does it get updated frequently? Are you open to using a mapping type instead? Hashing will be much faster than linear or even binary search (the 400k iterations matters)

Comment: big_DB is sorted and won't update during the project.

Comment: What dtype is it?

Comment: Also, are all rows guaranteed unique?

Comment: big_DB is sorted and don't update during the project (DB itself does update) Thanks for the comment I'll check Hashing

Comment: All float and ,,, unique in row

Comment: Are the rows unique though? My solution only works if you don't have duplicate rows.

Comment: Also if floats, no Nan, right?

Comment: It is hard to explain with my weak english. Here's example [a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1],[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f2],,,,[a1,bn,cn,dn,en,fn],[a2,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1]

Comment: Yes no Nan, only floats

Comment: Perfect. In that case my answer applies

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it now

Comment: Your English is fine BTW.

Comment: Wait. Is `big_DB` something like the result of `itertools.product`? Because if so, you can do this much faster than even a hash table.

Comment: Exactly. It IS the result of itertools.product

Comment: Could you add that to your question? I'm pretty sure you don't actually need to call `itertools.product`. If the floats are an arange or similar, the problem is trivial. If they are something else, it's still pretty simple. Especially if the search keys are guaranteed to be in the database

Comment: I'm going to leave my existing answer because it's legitimately useful on its own, but I think your problem is much simpler than you think.

Comment: I added that. Then I'll trying hashing first.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest I've been able to get this to work is using `O(1)` lookup using Python's builtin `dict` type. You need to pre-process your DB, which may take a second or two at most, but lookups go from >100ms on my machine to <50us: an improvement by 2000x or better for all 64 lookups. You may get slightly worse results because I tested with a 100k-element database. The larger DB you have may cause more hash collisions.

To make the lookup hash-table, I turned each row of `big_DB` into a bytes object. This makes up the key. Values are then indices of each element, since that's how you want to do the lookup:

```
dt = f'V{big_DB.shape[1] * big_DB.dtype.itemsize}'
dict_db = dict(zip(map(np.void.item, np.squeeze(big_DB.view(dt))), range(len(big_DB))))
```

The resulting lookup is as simple as

```
idx = dict_db[x.view(dt).item()]
```

Comment: what is x in 'idx = dict_db[x.view(dt).item()]' ?

Comment: This raise "descriptor 'item' for 'numpy.generic' objects doesn't apply to a 'numpy.ndarray' object"

Comment: In that case, you need to provide a complete MCVE. I made assumptions about how the arrays look, and apparently I was wrong.