# Apply Searchsorted to 3-D Array

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

Consider the following three-dimensional array of size `(1000,2000,200)` and corresponding two-dimensional array of size `(1000,2000)`. Both arrays do not contain NaNs:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,50,size=(1000,2000,200))
b = np.random.randint(0,50,size=(1000,2000,))
```

I'd like to find the appropriate index at a[i,j] that is closest to the single value at b[i,j]. The first approach was to use `np.searchsorted`:

indices = np.searchsorted(a, b)

However, the challenge is that this works only on 1-D dimensional arrays and returns (as anticipated) `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

I've inspected [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471109/how-to-vectorize-with-numpy-searchsorted-in-a-2d-array) related question, which is tailored to moving across a two-dimensional array. Is there a time-efficient method to return the indices at each point [i,j] instead of writing a non-vectorized function?

**Expansion:** I've made an alteration to the current approach, which use differential positioning across the entire array. This looks as follows:

```
b_3d: np.repeat(b[:, :, np.newaxis], a.shape[2], axis=2)
diff = np.abs(a - b_3d)
indices = np.argmin(diff, axis=2)
```

Comment: Maybe it help np.searchsorted(a.reshape(-1), b.reshape(-1)). Then you can find index from a, because you know shapes.

Comment: how do you define 'closest'?  With a 1d sorted numeric array, the relevant 'gap' is clear.  Not so with a multidim array.