# How to find insert location of each row in 2D array into another sorted 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a reference 2D numpy array `R` with 50k rows and 1k columns, which is sorted along axis 0. Given a query 1D array `x`, I can find the insert location of each value in `x` into each column of `R` with this code snippet:

```
R = np.array([[0, 8, 12, 2],
              [3, 16, 13, 5],
              [4, 19, 13, 11],
              [6, 23, 16, 12]])

x = np.array([4, 9, 17, 6])

# Desired output:
# array([2, 1, 4, 2])

idx = (R < x).sum(axis = 0)
```

The problem is, now I have a list of query arrays, `X`, where each row in `X` is a query array, and `X` can have as many rows as `R`. What is the best way to approach this?

I tried the following:

```
R = np.array([[0, 8, 12, 2],
              [3, 16, 13, 5],
              [4, 19, 13, 11],
              [6, 23, 16, 12]])

X = np.array([[4, 9, 17, 6],
              [1, 2, 12, 20]])

# Desired output:
# array([[2, 1, 4, 2],
#       [1, 0, 0, 4]])

# Approach 1 (requires too much memory):
idx = (R < X[:, None]).sum(axis = 1)


# Approach 2 (too slow):
idx = np.array([(R < x).sum(axis = 0) for x in X])
```

EDIT:
The `searchsorted2d(a, b)` function in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471109/how-to-vectorize-with-numpy-searchsorted-in-a-2d-array) does not solve the described problem. The input a is (m,n) 2D array and b is (m,) 1D array, whereas both of my arrays are 2D. It is possible to use `searchsorted2d` in the following manner:

```
idx = np.array([searchsorted2d(R.T, x.T) for x in X])
```

But this approach would still be slow. Is there a vectorized, more general alternative to `searchsorted2d` which would be more efficient?

Comment: Follow the duplicate link and use `searchsorted2d(R.T, x.T)`