# Search elements of one array in another, row-wise - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have a matrix of unique elements,

```
a=[
    [1,2,3,4],
    [7,5,8,6]
]
```

and another unique matrix filled with elements which has appeard in the first matrix.

```
b=[
    [4,1],
    [5,6]
]
```

And I expect the result of

```
[
    [3,0],
    [1,3]
].
```

That is to say, I want to find each row elements of b which equals to some elements of a in the same row, return the indices of these elements in a.
How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to consider each row independently and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array

Comment: It is not definitely sorted, I have changed the example.

Comment: Entries in `a` guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems to not to have any logic in your question? Could you explain which operation/process you wnat to do on it?

Comment: Would each row in a and b have unique elements?

Comment: a and b is unique, I have edited the problem.

Comment: @AgaigetSAgaigetS Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588862/ @Divakar
def searchsorted2d(a,b):
    m,n = a.shape
    max_num = np.maximum(a.max() - a.min(), b.max() - b.min()) + 1
    r = max_num*np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]
    p = np.searchsorted( (a+r).ravel(), (b+r).ravel() ).reshape(m,-1)
    return p - n*(np.arange(m)[:,None])

def search_indices(a, b):
    sidx = a.argsort(1)
    a_s = np.take_along_axis(a,sidx,axis=1)
    return np.take_along_axis(sidx,searchsorted2d(a_s,b),axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [54]: a
Out[54]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [7, 5, 8, 6]])

In [55]: b
Out[55]: 
array([[4, 1],
       [5, 6]])

In [56]: search_indices(a, b)
Out[56]: 
array([[3, 0],
       [1, 3]])
```

Another vectorized one leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
In [65]: (a[:,None,:]==b[:,:,None]).argmax(2)
Out[65]: 
array([[3, 0],
       [1, 3]])
```

Comment: @Navaro Well the usual NumPy way (under the hoods i.e. and the one that is performant) is with implementation in C. So, yes, it would be nice to see these being implemented in native NumPy. For now, I am just building up on existing tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using loops, here's a quick solution using np.where:

```
import numpy as np

a=[[1,2,3,4],
   [7,5,8,6]]
b=[[4,1],
   [5,6]]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.zeros_like(b)

for i in range(c.shape[0]):
    for j in range(c.shape[1]):
        _, pos = np.where(a==b[i,j])
        c[i,j] = pos

print(c.tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I process on huge data, there will be much slow. I want it solve in the matrix way, just because of the demand of faster processing speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
np.split(pd.DataFrame(a).where(pd.DataFrame(np.isin(a,b))).T.sort_values(by=[0,1])[::-1].unstack().dropna().reset_index().iloc[:,1].to_numpy(),len(a))                               

# [array([3, 0]), array([1, 3])]
```