# Numpy searchsorted along many dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to use `searchsorted()` along the first axis of an n dimensional array against an n-1 dimensional array. This is illustrated for a 3 dimensional array:

```py
def find(x,y):
    rows = np.zeros(y.shape, dtype=np.int)
    for ii in range(y.shape[0]):
        for jj in range(y.shape[1]):
            rows[ii, jj] = np.searchsorted(x[:, ii, jj], y[ii, jj])
    return rows


np.random.seed(42)
h = np.random.random((10,2,10))
h.sort(axis=0)
f = np.random.random((2,10))
print(find(h,f))
```

result is something like this:

```
[[10  0  3 10  5  0  1  5  0  6]
 [ 7  9  2  1 10  1  3  9  5 10]]
```

Obviously using those loops is probably slow and this solution does not extend to n dimensions. I am concerned with speed and `searchsorted()` is very fast on sorted arrays when compared to things like `argmax()` and `where()`.

Is there some way to apply `searchsorted()` along an axis like this without looping? The utility `apply_along_axis` kind of works, but makes a big array in 2 dimensions that you need to grab the diagonal of, which seems like a waste. I can't tell what it is doing in more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: In `find()` you assume that the first axis of `x` is sorted. However, with `h.sort()` the default will sort the array along the last axis. You should use `h.sort(axis=0)`.

Comment: I think your dimensions may not be right. Did you mean `h.sort(0)`? This would actually be faster if your sorted dimension was the last dimension, not the first.

Comment: I found a similar discussion:  [vectorized-searchsorted-numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588403/vectorized-searchsorted-numpy)

Comment: @Marc. Excellent find. I was working on a solution that's exactly along the lines of what Divakar suggested

Comment: Yes, should have been `sort(axis=0)`, but that's not really the point of the question. The linked discussion vectorizes the 2D solution, but doesn't address a nD solution.